# How to send emoji (not custom) throw the Telegram API

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I tried few variants. Like here:

[How to send Emoji with Telegram Bot API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430587/how-to-send-emoji-with-telegram-bot-api)

[python telegram telethon how to send emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549311/python-telegram-telethon-how-to-send-emoji)

And each variant of encoding from this page https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4b5/index.htm

But nothing helped for me.

I tried to escape backslashes and to not. So I get this `U0001F609` or this `\U0001F609` in Telegram message.

Can somebody just show me JSON which I have to send in order to finally receive a smiley in the message?

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Comment: I dont think my code will help.

Here is request data (POST method) https://prnt.sc/4rpoK6TJe7yD
Here is result https://prnt.sc/J-OunFC1EOAO

Here is code: https://prnt.sc/h2EnL2WBkwsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I see that in telegrams you need to send emoji as a UTF-8 entity (i.e.  / , etc.).

But my problem was that the text that the bot sends is regulated from the site's admin panel and stored in the database. And in the table, I cannot change the encoding for the correct storage of such characters (I get ???? at the output).

The solution I came up with:

Right now I'm storing an HTML entity in the database (i.e. `&#128285;` / `&#128181` etc.) and before sending the message, I cut them out of the regular expression `/&#.*;/mU` and convert to correct encoding with `mb_convert_encoding($match, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')`

I did not describe all these points in the original message because I myself did not fully understand why the telegram does not process what I am trying to send to it.